# how to use Utsaah font on Windows 10

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, language, microsoft-word-2016, localization

I have installed Utsaah font.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/utsaah

I want to type in Hindi. I have learned Hindi typing using US English Keyboard on Krutidev font.

https://www.indiatyping.com/index.php/typing-tutor/hindi-typing-tutor-krutidev

In Microsoft Office 2016 Professional plus

In fonts I select Krutidev and it comes directly.

I checked this website

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/fonts/windows_10_font_list#devanagari-supplemental-fonts

upon searching Krutidev I don't see it but it works.

I am trying to learn Utsaah font.

When I select Utsaah font in fonts in Office 2016 professional plus I do not get hindi text instead I get usual english words.

So I want to know how can I type using Utsaah font.I am on Windows 10.

https://smarttypingsolution.com/KeyboardLayout.html

Comment: “I don't see it but it works” - Please explain in explicit detail what you mean by this statement by editing your question

Comment: @Ramhound - I'm fairly certain he means that Krutidev isn't a listed font on the Microsoft Typography page linked in the question; that's because it's a third-party font, not one distributed with Windows or Office.

Comment: Krutidev is not an official font, you need to download it from elsewhere and use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Krutidev (a non-Microsoft font) was designed so that the Hindi characters replace the Latin characters, so that you can type in Hindi without having to reconfigure the computer to support the language separately. Most Microsoft fonts that allow typing in languages that do not use the Latin alphabet, including Utsaah for Hindi, are designed to conform to the Unicode standard. In order to use a Unicode-conformant font for such a language, you will need to install the foreign language's input method/keyboard in Windows; this can be found in Windows Settings>Time & Language>Region & Language.

Once you have installed the Hindi keyboard driver, you switch to the Hindi keyboard and you will be able to type in Hindi in Word, Excel, or any app that supports font selection.

[Managing alternate Keyboard Layouts in Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-your-keyboard-layout-windows-10)